# What to call "a T-shirt without sleeves"?

Tags: word-request

> **[T-shirt](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/t-shirt?q=t-shirt)**: an informal shirt with short sleeves and no collar or buttons, or just a few buttons at the top

[image]

But, what to call "**a T-shirt without sleeves**" like this:

[image]

Some say "**[muscle Ts](https://www.thefactshop.com/fashion-facts/t-shirt-sleeve-types)**" or **[vest](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/vest)**

> **[vest]** 1 /vest/ ●●○ noun [countable]
>
> 1 British English a piece of underwear without sleeves that you wear
>   on the top half of your body SYN undershirt American English

But a child can wear a vest when they go out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is called a **tank top** (or simply tank shirt/tank). Of course, the more generic term "*sleeveless shirt*" is also used.

The term you mentioned, "vest", is a British English name for this type of garment. Vests in the U.S. are different (with buttons).

Comment: The British 'vest' was _originally_ only worn as underwear, but in these less formal times a garment of the same shape can be worn uncovered in hot weather.